# SCCM Create Application

Tags: windows, sccm

I am attempting to create application with SCCM so that I can install Chrome on our systems. SCCM is installed on the Domain Controller and the .msi file is located on the E drive on the DC. I opened SCCM as administrator. I am getting the following error in the Create Application Wizard after browsing to the .msi file location and clicking next.

"The specificed file does not exist or the computer running the configuration manager console has no read permissions to the specified file"

I have tried changing different options for the path:

```
E:\path\file.msi
\\E:\path\file.msi
\\path\file.msi
```

Each attempt gets the same error. My user is in the SCCM Admin group, and I have tried putting the Domain Controller into the SCCM Admin group as well.

Is there a setting that I am not doing correctly?

Comment: So is your DC also your site server or is the SCCM Console Installed on the DC?

Answer (score 0):

Give your logged in user explicit R/W permission on the folder containing this file.